# Filter Collection- Show all selected filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, shopify

I've got a problem with my filters.
My Website is: https://webiloot.com/

Currently, when going in a collection you can pick one filter from each group.
My problem is that the filter system is showing products containing for example: Thor AND Batman. Instead, I need it to show products containing Thor OR Batman.

I understand how the filter system works, it creates a new URL joining each filter with '+' sign.

I don't need help writing code (therefore, I'm not pasting any).
My question is what should the URL look like to acheive my goal?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot currently create a URL ORing tags. See https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/filtering-a-collection-using-multiple-tags-and-vs-or-324651

I've done it in the past with AJAX calls

Comment: Ok, I'll see what I can do in the mean time. Thanks!